# Limits of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is there any difference between the

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx $$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to b^-} \int_a^x f(x) dx \qquad \text{OR}\qquad \lim_{x\to a^+} \int_x^b f(x) dx$$

When would one need the second versions of the integrals, is it when there are discontinuities at the end points?

Comment: When the discontinuity is in $b$ use left, when in $a$ use right. When in both separate in two integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$. Then $\int_{[0,1]} f(x)$ does not exist. It is not Riemann integrable in the ordinary sense. However, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} \int_{x}^{1} = 2\cdot 1^{1/2} - 0 = 2$. Also note that the other limit does not exist. So, these three expressions are not equivalent. Note that if it is Riemann integrable in the ordinary sense (that is the first integral exists), then it is also integrable in the extended sense and so it also exists in the extended sense. Then all three integrals are equal.

Now, the same is true in the Lebesgue case.